# Launch a program on boot (Debian server)

Tags: linux, debian, init.d

Path to folder: `root/CumulusServer`

Command to execute: `./CumulusServer --daemon [--pidfile=/var/run/CumulusServer.pid]`

I've spent considerable time trying to figure out how to modify `init.d`? Any help would be appreciated in resolving this issue.

---

Errors:

```
[FAILED] cd /root/CumulusServer | ./CumulusServer --daemon [--pidfile=/var/run/CumulusServer.pid] to /etc/rc.local

[FAILED] /root/CumulusServer | ./CumulusServer --daemon [--pidfile=/var/run/CumulusServer.pid] to /etc/rc.local

[FAILED] cd /root/CumulusServer && ./CumulusServer --daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind this command being the last thing to run at boot time, drop it into `/etc/rc.local`.

Note that `rc.local` usually contains a statement like `exit 0`, make sure to add your command before it so it actually runs.

For more sophisticated actions and to allow this daemon to be stopped/(re)started manually after boot, you will want to add this command to its own file under `/etc/init.d` as you have initially tried. Take a look at [this Debian Wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) to help you get started.

Comment: I'm familiar with Windows this is embarassing. What would the line be? root/CumulusServer./CumulusServer --daemon [--pidfile=/var/run/CumulusServer.pid] in one single line before exit 0?

Comment: I tried the two examples above (see my edited post any help would be appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

Disregard `cd`, `|` and `&&`.  You just need to use the absolute(full) path to the CumulusServer file you're trying to execute.  Additionally, you can remove the brackets `[ ]` from the `--pidfile` option.  When showing examples of a program's command line syntax, brackets denote an optional section of the command and they aren't actually used.

This will insert your command into rc.local, above exit 0:

```
$ sudo sed -i '/^exit/ i\/root/CumulusServer/CumulusServer --daemon --pidfile=/var/run/CumulusServer.pid\' /etc/rc.local
```